# Problem exporting from shotwell (imagenes with same name on differents dates)

Tags: shotwell

I have about 1100 pics on shotwell.
I need to export all.

so I select all, and export them to a folder.
The problem is that differents images have the same name and because it was on differents events inside shotwell this is not a problem but when I export them... it result only in about 800.

if I export them in batches of let say... 100.. it ask sometime if I replace an existing one... but it does not allow me to give another name!
(also I suspect it is not asking me on every one)

any ideas???

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pyRenamer](https://launchpad.net/pyrenamer).  With pyRenamer you can change the name of several files at the same time easily.

To install pyRenamer, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install pyrenamer
```

Or, just click [**pyRenamer** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/pyrenamer/)

Once installed, you can rename your files, and then export them as you want.